# Error in a LINQ query

Tags: c#, linq

I have a problem with this query:

```
var res = from c in db.Client
          where db.TimesheetLine.Select(o => o.ClientId && 
                                             o.TimesheetId == timesheetId)
                                .Contains(c.Id)
          select c;
```

I have the error message:

> Operator '&&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'int?' and 'bool'.

**All I wanna do is to select all the clients which are in a timesheetline X**

I have the client class and the timesheetline class

```
public class CLient 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ClientName { get; set; }
}

public class TimesheetLine
{
    public int TimesheetLineId { get; set; }
    public int TimesheetId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public double Duration { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ClientId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ClientAddressId { get; set; }
    public int ActivityTypeId { get; set; }
    public string Overtime { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Activity Activity { get; set; }
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
    public virtual ClientAddress ClientAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual Timesheet Timesheet { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `o.ClientId` doesn't return a boolean.

Comment: yep the compiler tells you all

Comment: What is confusing about that error message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could make a `join`

```
var res = from client in db.Client
          join timesheetLine in db.TimesheetLine
          on client.Id equals timesheetLine.ClientId.GetValueOrDefault()
          where timesheetLine.timesheetId == timesheetId
          select client;
```

The interesting part here is that we want to base our join on the value of a nullable int,  `timesheetLine.ClientId` and an int, `client.Id`. In order we make it, we use the `GetValueOrDefault` method that returns the default value of the nullable, when the nullable has not a value. In this case the value that will be returned would be 0. **Assuming** that there isn't any client with `Id` the above works. Differently, we have to change it a bit.

Comment: `Client` does not have `TimesheetId `, `TimesheetLine` has navigation property.

Comment: @mo.esmp oops you are correct. Your post edited again and I didn;t nocticed on the initial post. Please see my update in a few minutes. Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Try using a different query:

```
var res = (from ts in db.TimesheetLine
           where ts.TimesheetId == timesheetId)
           select ts.Client).ToList();
```

Iterate through the TimsheetLine data, picking out the clients associated with a specific timesheet.

You could do a null check just in case:

```
var res = (from ts in db.TimesheetLine
           where ts.TimesheetId == timesheetId && ts.Client != null)
           select ts.Client).ToList();
```

Comment: based on "All I wanna do is to select all the clients which are in a timesheetline X", this is the answer I'd go with (note that the others aren't invalid LINQ queries that I can see, but I think this one hits the mark of what you're going for)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot write conditional statement inside `Select`. You can use `Any` instead:

```
  var res = from c in db.Client
            where db.TimesheetLine.Any(o => o.ClientId == c.Id)
            select c;
```